# Getting Google calendar to set no reminders by default

Tags: google-calendar

Every time I make an event on google calendar, it sets two reminders an email and an alert both for 10 minutes before the event starts. I don't want these reminders. Ever. How do I modify it so that the default is to have no reminders set?

Comment: Questions on Super User are expected to generally relate to computer software or computer hardware in some way, within the scope defined in the faq. - Questions about web apps are considered off topic on Supseruser. Questions about web apps can be asked on a sister website http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Until the new stackexchange site is out of beta and set up permanently, I don't think SU should exclude web apps from its scope.

Comment: Actually, ignore previous comment. I didn't realise that web apps were never in SU's scope. [I've had a similar discussion about the LaTeX tag on SO and the new TeX site, but I see now this is a different issue...]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go into *Settings -> Calendar Settings -> Calendars*.  You'll see all of your calendars listed.  On the line for each one is a *Notifications* link.  Click that, and there's a setting for *Event reminders: Unless otherwise specified by the individual event.*  You should be able to remove the default reminders there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using normal Google Calendar, or the Calendar in Google Apps?

I'm on on Google Apps and there are no reminders set when I create calendar entries in my account. I thought it would be in the "Calendar Settings" (link in top right of webpage) but I looked in my settings and didn't find any presets about this.

Do you have any Google Labs item enabled that might cause this? I'm not aware of any such item, but perhaps you have a different set than what I have available.